# Why is visual studio looking for a folder that does not exits?

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an application in visual studio 2010. Everything was working fine until I added the  in the master page. I'm getting an error.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /MymindProject/Account/Login.aspx

The weird thing is that I deleted that folder and visual studio still looking for .aspx pages in that directory. This happened after I put the logged in status control in the list . Does any body know how to fix this error? I appreciated very much...

Comment: First thing I would do is to search the entire solution for parts of the path, to see if it is configured somewhere.

Comment: Hi Chris, I looked in all my aspx files and the Full Path is C:\Users\Marlo Briones\Desktop\MymindProject\Login2.aspx and it is still trying to look for        http://localhost:2683/MymindProject/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMymindProject%2fLogin2.aspx

Comment: Hmmm... Did you stop to think that you're getting the error BECAUSE you deleted the folder? It's not weird at all that you get an error when you delete something that another part of your app depends on.

Comment: Hi Erik, I did think that that, but there are no dependencies related to the login.aspx.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I finally found the problem, it had to do with the configuration file.

Comment: Could you post the resolution, someone else may find it a useful pointer in the future?

Comment: Yes, the path in the configuration was something else. so I just configured the right path on the configuration file.